Properties of conjugate transpose
I need to define the properties of conjugate transpose in mathematica:
Properties of Conjugate Transpose:
    ConT[A_ + B_] := ConjugateTranspose[A] + ConjugateTranspose[B]
    ConT[c_*a_ ** b_^2] := c*ConjugateTranspose[a] ** ConjugateTranspose[b^2]    


so that I can

ConT[I*\[HBar]*(\[Kappa]/2)*
   subs[a, 2] ** (subsup[a, 1, \[Dagger]])^2 + 
  I*\[HBar]*subs[\[ScriptCapitalE], 2]*subsup[a, 2, \[Dagger]]]

However I can't perform the conjugate transform.

Only one of the 2 definitions gets ever applied, because, after applying one, "ConT" disappeared.

Is there any alternative way?

E.g. define ConT[A_ + B_] in terms of ConT
